# Testing a AFNetworking API with Kiwi

Tags: ios, mocking, afnetworking, kiwi

I'm writing some tests for a networking API with kiwi.

Here is the relevant code:

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
MyAPI.h
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
@protocol MyAPIDelegate<NSObject>

-(void) onMyMethodCall:(id)response;
-(void) onFail:(NSError*)error message:(NSString*)message;

@end

@interface MyAPI : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<MyAPIDelegate> delegate;

-(void) myMethodCall;

@end
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
MyAPI.m
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
@synthesize delegate    

-(void) myMethodCall
{
  NSDictionary *params = [Dictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"value1" forKey:@"param1"];
  [self apiCallWithServerPath:@"logic/myMethodCall"
                   parameters:params
                    onSuccess:^(id response) {
                        [delegate onMyMethodCall];
                    }
                    onFailure:^(NSError *error, NSString* msg) {
                        [delegate onFail:error message:msg];
                    }];
}

-(void) apiCallWithServerPath:(NSString *)serverPath parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters onSuccess:(void (^)(id))success onFailure:(void (^)(NSError *, NSString *))failure
{
    AFHTTPClient *client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL urlWithString:@"http://www.myserver.com/"]];
    [client setParameterEncoding:AFFormURLParameterEncoding];

    [client postPath:serverPath
          parameters:parameters
             success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
               id response = [[JSONDecoder decoder] objectWithData:responseObject];
               success(response);
             }
             failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
               NSLog(@"API call failed:  error message = %@",[error localizedDescription]);
                failure(error, [error localizedRecoverySuggestion]);
             }];
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
MyAPITest.m
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
SPEC_BEGIN(MyAPITest)

describe(@"MyAPITest should", ^{
    __block MyAPI *api;
    __block MyAPI *delegateMock;

    beforeEach(^{
        delegateMock = [KWMock mockForProtocol:@protocol(MyAPIDelegate)];
        api = [[MyAPI alloc] init];
        api.delegate = delegateMock;
    });

    afterEach(^{
        delegateMock = nil;
        api = nil;
    });

    it(@"should go to the server and get an answer, dont care about the value atm", ^{
        [[api should] receive:@selector(myMethodCall)];

        KWCaptureSpy *spy = [delegateMock captureArgument:@selector(onMyMethodCall:) atIndex:0];

        // I usually put a breakpoint here... 
        [api myMethodCall];

        [[expectFutureValue(spy.argument) shouldEventually] beNonNil];
    });
});

SPEC_END
```

This is a very simple test, that I'm building incrementally.  Eventually I'd like to test the values inside spy.argument, but for now i'm only interested in making sure that it is not nil.

Running the test always fails with: [FAILED] Argument requested has yet to be captured.

**Debugging doesn't work**:  When I try to put breakpoint in the test (where the comment says) its **never steps into** the method.

At the same time, if I put NSLog(s) inside MyAPI's myMethodCall, they are **not printed on console.**

Any help would be much appreciated.

/////////////////////// UPDATE //////////////////////////////////

Turns out that if I comment/remove this line (from the test):

```
[[api should] receive:@selector(myMethodCall)];
```

The test works.  Any idea of why this line is causing the problem?

Comment: Is strange that the log messages don't appear!? The method onMyMethodCall has one param. Maybe the missing colon? [delegateMock captureArgument:@selector(onMyMethodCall:) atIndex:0];

Comment: actually, the actual code there does have the colon.  (Didn't copy~paste)....